# Android: UI Linear Layout and Buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I am having 8(Eight) buttons in one line(horizontal) under one linear layout. The problem is that these buttons look like rectangle whereas I want them to look like square.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.125" 
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

Can someone guide me what needs to be done so that these rectangles become squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use fixed dimensions for both width and height, you'll get a square, but you lose the nice auto-sizing LinearLayout does. In your case, you don't know the width of each button until *after* the layout is finished. The post() method in View is your friend.

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button25);
first.post( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button1.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = button1.getWidth();
    }
});
```

To make sure buttons size correctly your layout should look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"> <!-- or however many buttons there are -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- other buttons go here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

This only takes care of the first button, but you can figure out how to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Assign the values for width and height as

```
    android:layout_width="160dip"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
```

Also remove

```
   android:layout_weight="0.125"
```

So the code is like

```
       <Button
    android:id="@+id/button25"
    android:layout_width="160dip"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right"

    android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

It Works!